# Graph-tool: How to access vertex index based on vp property

Tags: indexing, properties, vertex, graph-tool

I'm trying to get vertex index based on a property by applying graph_tool.util.find_vertex function.
Applying `find_vertex(g, prop, label)` return me `[<Vertex object with index '2' at 0x7f21e19b2820>]`
I don't know how get the index in this text. It seem that is it a vertex object.
Could some one help me. Thanks